# How to solve AttributeError: Can't get attribute on<module 'x.py'> error?

Tags: python, class, import, pytorch

I have two files `x.py` and `y.py`.

Inside `y.py`, there are two classes, `A` and `B`. Class `A` calls class `B` inside `run` function.

In file `x.py`, I imported class `A` to run it:

```
from y import A
obj = A()
obj.run()
```

I got this error:
`AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'B' on <module '__main__' from 'x.py'>`

I found actually the solution here: [AttributeError: Can't get attribute on <module '**main**' from 'manage.py'>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45483349/attributeerror-cant-get-attribute-on-module-main-from-manage-py), which simple solves this error by importing class `B` inside file `x.py`:

```
from y import A, B
```

I feel this is not the right way to do it if I want to build a python library. I don't think you need always to do that when you call a class from a library.

How can I solve this issue in the "right way" from a software engineer perspective?

## Edit: adding an example

Class `B` is `RoBerta_CLS`.

file `x.py`:

```
# from y import RoBerta_CLS
from y import A

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = A(model_path='/home/PATH/models/DistilRoBERTa/')
```

file `y.py`:

```
import torch, os
import torch.nn as nn
from transformers import RobertaForSequenceClassification
device = 'cuda'

class RoBerta_CLS(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, model_params):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder = RobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_params['MODEL'], num_labels=1)
        self.encoder = self.encoder.to(device)

    def save_pretrained(self, output_model_file):
        torch.save(self, output_model_file + 'pytorch_model.pt')
        print('saved..')
    
    @staticmethod
    def from_pretrained(output_model_file):
        model = torch.load(os.path.join(output_model_file, 'pytorch_model.pt'))
        print('loaded..')
        return model


class A:
    
    def __init__(self, model_path=''):
        self.model = RoBerta_CLS.from_pretrained(model_path)
```

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Comment: You shouldn't need to import B in to `x.py` if it doesn't call `B` itself. The code from `y.py` runs in its own namespace.

Comment: @Barmar I added an example.

Comment: I agree with you @Barmar, I just noticed that, maybe I have another error.

Answer (score 0):

That's very interesting. I don't have the same issue here. Could you post some code that's giving you the issue?

Update #1:

Here's mine:

`x.py`

```
# from y import RoBerta_CLS
from y import A

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = A(model_path='/home/PATH/models/DistilRoBERTa/')
    print("if you see this, it means the program ran without errors")
```

`y.py`

```
device = 'cuda'

class RoBerta_CLS(object):

    def __init__(self, model_params):
        pass

    def save_pretrained(self, output_model_file):
        pass
    
    @staticmethod
    def from_pretrained(output_model_file):
        pass

class A:
    
    def __init__(self, model_path=''):
        self.model = RoBerta_CLS.from_pretrained(model_path)
```

```
python3 x.py
if you see this, it means the program ran without errors
```

Comment: Maybe I have another issue. I just added an example.

Comment: updated my code as well using your example without pytorch, and worked. i believe its a pytorch-related issue and not python

Comment: I found the error, it's because of this line: `model = torch.load(os.path.join(output_model_file, 'pytorch_model.pt'))`, but it's not clear why!

Comment: nice, at least we're getting somewhere. does `os.path.join(output_model_file, 'pytorch_model.pt')` exist?

Comment: yes, it works when I uncomment this line in `x.py` : `from y import RoBerta_CLS`